# How to fetch one row inside a group in mysql according to a criteria in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table like this with 8 rows

```sql
+----+------+------+--------+
| id | type | attr1 | attr2 |
+----+------+-------+-------+
|  1 |    a |  abcd |  qwer |
|  2 |    a |  efgh |  tyui |
|  2 |    b |  ijkl |  opas |
|  3 |    a |  mnop |  dfgh |
|  4 |    a |  qrst |  jklz |
|  5 |    a |  uvwx |  xcvb |
|  5 |    b |  yzab |  nmqw |
|  6 |    b |  cdef |  erty |
+----+------+-------+-------+
```

It is known than type can be either `'a'` or `'b'`.

I need to select the rows in such a way that if there are more than one rows with same `id`, then select the one with type `'a'`. Else select the row with whatever type is present.

So my desired result should be like

```sql
+----+------+------+--------+
| id | type | attr1 | attr2 |
+----+------+-------+-------+
|  1 |    a |  abcd |  qwer |
|  2 |    a |  efgh |  tyui |
|  3 |    a |  mnop |  dfgh |
|  4 |    a |  qrst |  jklz |
|  5 |    a |  uvwx |  xcvb |
|  6 |    b |  cdef |  erty |
+----+------+-------+-------+
```

I have a MySQL query

```sql
SELECT t.id,      
    CASE
        WHEN count(t.id) > 1 THEN 'a'
        ELSE t.type
    END `type`
FROM table1 t
GROUP BY  t.id
ORDER BY  t.type ASC
```

which gives this result

```sql
+----+------+
| id | type |
+----+------+
|  1 |    a |
|  2 |    a |
|  3 |    a |
|  4 |    a |
|  5 |    a |
|  6 |    b |
+----+------+
```

But I need the respective row with all columns.
How to do that?

Note that the MySQL version that I have is `5.7.12`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention if multiple a's with the same id are possible or what to do in that case.  I'm going to assume you want all a rows included.  To do that, you just need to exclude b rows when there is a corresponding a row:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
left join table1 t2 on t2.id=t.id and t.type='b' and t2.type='a'
where t2.id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

you also can do it using `window function`:

```
select * from 
 ( 
  select * , row_number() over (partition by id order by case when type = 'a' then 0 else 1 end) rn
 ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I would be inclined to use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.type = 'a' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.type = 'a'
                 );
```